# HTML5 - Canvas Event Handling library?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, canvas

Is there any JS API/Library for HTML5 Canvas which I can use for registering events & event handling as done in ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 0):

[EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) (beta) might be worth a look. It was produced by Grant Skinner who has always been very active in the Flash community and aims to provide an API "loosely based on Flash's display list". The [API documentation](http://easeljs.com/docs/) looks pretty complete and indicates that the library supports the standard set of mouse events for display objects.